# Reliability of GERMAN "Spelling & Grammar" check in Microsoft Word?

Tags: grammatical-case, spelling

When transcribing handwritten German texts, I easily recognize most words; i.e. my ***passive*** command of German is quite good.
However, due to unclear handwriting IN COMBINATION WITH my lack of "internalized" German grammatical knowledge, I do often have problems with interpreting whether the handwriting says "die", "der", "das" or "den". I do also often have problemns with interpreting the last inflection/conjugation derived letters in a word written in unclear handwriting. I.e. my ***active*** command of German is not good.

Microsoft Word (Review -> "Spelling & Grammar") has a spelling and grammar control function, which is highlighted in this way:
**"Typos? Not on our watch. Let us check your spelling & grammar"**.

I would lilke to learn from persons aquainted with this Microsoft Word function how reliable this function is when it comes to a combined grammar and derived spelling (or vice versa) control verification of GERMAN texts, taking into account that German grammatically is quite a complicated language ...

Comment: Sorry, that is even by technical standard to hard to measure. As a native speaker I somewhat have an idea when to rely and when to ignore the auto correct. So I let MS Word do as least auto correct as possible - more the typos are a convenient feature (nciht/DAs/..).